# How to make a delete function for a Linked-List in Python

Tags: python, class, linked-list, nonetype

I am ongoing an online course which includes actions with linked lists in Python. The exercise is to make get_position, insert and delete actions for a linked list class and then get the required results commented at the bottom of the script. I have been stuck on the delete function for the past few days and I can't see the (maybe obvious) solution.

My code looks like this:

```
"""The LinkedList code from before is provided below.
Add three functions to the LinkedList.
"get_position" returns the element at a certain position.
The "insert" function will add an element to a particular
spot in the list.
"delete" will delete the first element with that
particular value.
Then, use "Test Run" and "Submit" to run the test cases
at the bottom."""

class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        
    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element
            
    def get_position(self, position):
        """Get an element from a particular position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Return "None" if position is not in the list."""
        current = self.head
        i = 1
        if self.head:
            while i < position:
                current = current.next
                i = i + 1
            return current
        else:
            return None
    
    def insert(self, new_element, position):
        """Insert a new node at the given position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Inserting at position 3 means between
        the 2nd and 3rd elements."""
        current = self.head
        i = 1
        if self.head:
            while i < position - 1:
                current = current.next
                i = i + 1
            current.next = new_element
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
        else:
            self.head = new_element
        pass
    
    
    def delete(self, value):
        """Delete the first node with a given value."""
        if self.head is None:
            raise Exception("List is empty")
        
        if self.head.value == value:
            self.head = self.head.next
            current = self.head
            i = 1
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            return
        
        previous = self.head
        for element in self:
            if element.value == value:
                previous.next = element.next
                return
            previous = element

# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a LinkedList
ll = LinkedList(e1)
ll.append(e2)
ll.append(e3)

# Test get_position
# Should print 3
print ll.head.next.next.value
# Should also print 3
print ll.get_position(3).value

# Test insert
ll.insert(e4,3)
# Should print 4 now
print ll.get_position(3).value

# Test delete
ll.delete(1)
# Should print 2 now
print ll.get_position(1).value
# Should print 4 now
print ll.get_position(2).value
# Should print 3 now
print ll.get_position(3).value
```

The only value I can't get is the last one and this is the error screen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "vm_main.py", line 31, in <module> 
    import main 
  File "/tmp/workspaces/04497b9c-ee1c-47bc-9e15-b58ef0e5580c/main.py", line 2, in <module> 
    import studentMain 
  File "/tmp/workspaces/04497b9c-ee1c-47bc-9e15-b58ef0e5580c/studentMain.py", line 2, in <module> 
    import algorithmsP2 
  File "/tmp/workspaces/04497b9c-ee1c-47bc-9e15-b58ef0e5580c/algorithmsP2.py", line 112, in <module> 
    print ll.get_position(3).value 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Edit:
I found the fix. It was the insert method acting up so I changed it to

```
    def insert(self, new_element, position):
        """Insert a new node at the given position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Inserting at position 3 means between
        the 2nd and 3rd elements."""
        current = self.head
        i = 1
        if self.head:
            while i < position - 1:
                current = current.next
                i = i + 1
            that = current.next
            new_element.next = that
            current.next = new_element
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
        else:
            self.head = new_element
```

Comment: Please post your traceback as text and not as an image.

Comment: How did you verify that `delete` works properly?

Comment: Ok, I edited it to make the traceback readable

Comment: Please format the traceback properly.

Comment: @ScottHunter the rows for getting the position of the 1 and 2 indexes seem to work fine and show the wanted results

Comment: But since it clearly can't get the 3rd element, and it could *before* the delete, it *isn't* working properly.

Comment: @MichaelButscher maybe the traceback is formatted better now?

Comment: You ask about the delete function, but your insert function is not working correctly either.

Comment: @ScottHunter yea, I thought of this also. But I can't figure it out - the only things that I personally added were append and insert, but after trying them with different examples they seem to work, although they are not pretty

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Yes, traceback is now easier to read. The problem begins already with the `insert` method because it doesn't adjust the `next` attribute of the newly inserted element. Elements after the inserted one aren't in the chain anymore.

Comment: @trincot fair point, but then why am I getting the right answers to all my requests and only the last one fails? Shouldn't I encounter a problem immediately after the insert row?

Comment: Also wrong code produces a correct result once in a while. It means the testing code is not thorough enough ;-)

Comment: @trincot true :D

Comment: Why are you using Python 2 though? That was sunset 3 years ago... If you are following a course that still uses Python 2, you should maybe look for an up to date course. It's a pity to spend time on a version of the language that is not maintained anymore.

Comment: So the main takeaway is that I should redo my insert function to have the next property for the new element as @MichaelButscher mentioned?

Comment: Deleting the head element works correctly but because `insert` doesn't actually add an element, the list is shorter than expected after deleting the head element.

Comment: Yes you should focus on insert first, and you should test your code with more than just that main code you got. Make sure to test insert with a list of a few elements, and insert at position 1, at a position in the middle, and at the last possible position, and verify the result.

Comment: `delete` also needs work yet. It can currently only delete the first element.

Comment: To help you debug your program, make a print method, so you can at least simply view what the list looks like at any moment.